# Required DLL marked as unused by Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, openxml

I have a project which builds a DLL (I'll call it `mylibrary.dll`). `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` is used by several classes in mylibrary and therefore is a dependency. My project builds successfully and outputs both my `mylibrary.dll` and a local copy of `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`. All good so far.

Now I have a new project in a new solution (call it `mywebapi`). I include references to both `mylibrary.dll` and `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`. The project builds successfully and everything is fine.

Here's the trouble, in my project settings, if I have Visual Studio check for "Unused References..." it is telling me that `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` is not used and should therefore be removed. But if I do not include it in my release, the classes referencing it fail cause the dll is missing.

Is it possible to mark it as a chained reference? Or somehow otherwise tell Visual Studio that it is a dependency?

Comment: You must be doing something odd. You shouldn't need a direct reference from `mywebapi` to `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` if you use no types from that assembly and if the types you're using from `mylibrary.dll` don't expose you to those types (by e.g. having such types in the signatures of methods that you're calling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question. Never found a solution. But this is probably irrelevant now with newer versions of VS.